# How to design a Data Model for a Servant Management System with Roles

Tags: database, database-design

I am trying to manage roles but I am stuck in role management. I am working on servant management system.  I have servant in my system , user and admin

I have created a role table and manage role table

```
user table
-----------
user_id   user_name   user_pass
  1          abc        xyz
```

this is my role table

```
role table
-----------
r_id  r_name
  1   customer
  2   servant
  3   admin
```

and manage role table

```
manage role table
------------------
r_id  u_id
  1    1
  1    2
  2    3
```

Now the problem is i have a hire table i want to see which user has hire which servant

```
hire table
----------
c_id , s_id
```

**what is the best way to represent hire table because I want to see which customer has hire which servant through id?**

Answer (score 0):

**First of All**: there is no need to **Reinventing the wheel.**

In Data Modeling world, we have some patterns to your problem:

Context-based access control (CBAC) 
Data-centric security 
Discretionary access control (DAC)
Graph-based access control (GBAC)
Lattice-based access control (LBAC)
Mandatory access control (MAC)
Organisation-based access control (OrBAC)
Role-based access control (RBAC)
Rule-set-based access control (RSBAC)
Attribute-based-access-control (ABAC)

I offer to use **RBAC (Role-Based Access Control)**.

**And now:** 
After applying RBAC in your project, you have 2 ways to use RBAC data into your project's tables:

1. If you want to save a user that performs something (e.g. hire), just add `user_id` as foreign key into that table.
2. If user has more than 1 role, just add `user_id` and `role_id` as foreign keys into that table.

to your final question: just add their `id`'s as foreign keys to new table.